# Retrieving the content rather than the headers

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I am trying to retrieve the content from a PostgreSQL table using the following Python code. However, the code keeps sending me the table header. Is there something wrong with my code?

```
def retrieve_info(parameter, identity_number):
    statement = """SELECT %s from "service_reviews_serviceprovider" WHERE identification_number = %s"""
    cur.execute(statement, (parameter, identity_number, ))
    cur.connection.commit()
    result = cur.fetchone()[0]
    print(result)
    return result
```

Comment: There's no need to commit for select statement

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. However, the problem still remains.

Comment: That's odd, your code seems to be correct to me. What does the query return if you perform it directly in psql?

Comment: It keeps printing the name of the field instead of the content.

Comment: @AnishShah Actually, a commit (or rollback) is appropriate after `SELECT` if you're not in autocommit mode. It's best not to leave a transaction open indefinitely. It also provides explicit transaction delineation, and if you're in `SERIALIZABLE` mode is necessary to ensure you see fresh data. It's good practice you should not discourage.